# SQL - duplicates - query form one table

Tags: sql

I have a problem with query, this is only part of it but i have problem with selecting not duplicates values.

```
TABLE par 
ProdID     ParID    Value
23462       5         1
23462       6         4
237         5         2
237         6         1
178         2         1
```

When i executing this query:

```
SELECT 
 par.ProdID
FROM
  par
WHERE
  ((par.ParID= 6 AND par.Value < 99) OR 
  (par.ParID= 5 AND par.Value < 99)) AND 
  par.ProdID = 23462
```

I'm getting this result:

```
ProdID
23462
23462
```

When i change OR to AND i'll not get any result.
How to change query that it will only show 1 result ? 
Its only part of query and i cannot use DISTINCT or LIMIT.

Thank You.

Comment: Use `SELECT min(par.ProdID)` for instance. BTW your `where` clause can be simplified to `WHERE par.Value < 99 and par.ProdID = 23462 and par.ParID in (5,6)`
  `

Comment: It returns 2 results, there's not going to be any way to get one row without using distinct or a group by aggregate function or using some other criteria that only matches one row (or limit). Use a subquery? Then the group by won't affect the overall result from your full query.

Answer (score 0):

You have two results with 23462 which satisfy the condition which you are giving hence it is returning two rows. You may try this:

```
SELECT 
 min(par.ProdID)
FROM
  par
WHERE
  ((par.ParID= 6 AND par.Value < 99) OR 
  (par.ParID= 5 AND par.Value < 99)) AND 
  par.ProdID = 23462
```

Comment: I cannot add "top 1" from the same reason that i cannot use DISTINCT or LIMIT its only part of large query.

Answer (score 0):

You could `group by` `ProdID`:

```
select
    par.ProdID
from
    par
where
  ((par.ParID= 6 AND par.Value < 99) OR 
  (par.ParID= 5 AND par.Value < 99)) AND 
  par.ProdID = 23462
group by 
    ProdID
```

**Example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75998/3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Distinct` to get duplicate values only once in your result set.But you should be careful because `Distinct` is somehow slower than writing an efficient query that It does the trick without using `Distinct`:

So you can write :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 par.ProdID
FROM
  par
WHERE
  ((par.ParID= 6 AND par.Value < 99) OR 
  (par.ParID= 5 AND par.Value < 99)) AND 
  par.ProdID = 23462
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this...

```
WITH CTE_RESULT AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY PRODID) ROW_NO, ProdID, ParID, Value
    FROM
    #par A
    WHERE
    A.ParID IN (5,6) AND A.Value < 99   
 )
 SELECT * FROM CTE_RESULT C WHERE C.ROW_NO =1  --AND C.ProdID=23462
```